# Selectable tool-tip hovering an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that this question is rather vague but I couldn't find much information regarding to my problem.
Basically, what I want to achieve, is a tool-tip that doesn't disappear when I hover it, allowing me to select its text.

Is this possible or do I have to create a `div` simulating the tool-tip?

For instance:

```
<a id="foo">hover me</a>
<div class="box" id="tooltip">item 1<br/>item 2<br/>item 3<br/></div>
```

In this case, the `div` would appear as a tool-tip of `foo`.

Comment: do you use a library?

Comment: I am using bootsrap, but their tooltips are just normal ones.

Comment: Then your only option is javascript, create a listener for hovering your element then after a while disappear the tooltip

Comment: if you use jquery try tiptip tooltip library.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using transition property:

```
<style>
    .tooltip:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "";
    }
    .tooltip:hover:after { 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity  0s linear 1s;
    content: " some text you want to keep ";
    }
</style>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">What am I?</a>
```